# Plus and Minus Qty within Loop

Tags: php, jquery

I currently have a -/+ quantity feature setup and working, but when adding this to a loop the quantity amount duplicates to each input when clicking the -/+ buttons - please see attached.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCZeS.png)

Any help and advice would be helpful.

**PHP**

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
                echo '<li id="'.$subID.'">'.get_the_title().' - £'.$price .' - ID '.$product->id.' ';
                echo '<form id="'.$product->id.'" method="POST" action="#">';
                echo '<input type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus" field="quantity" />';
                echo '<input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" class="qty" />';
                echo '<input type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus" field="quantity" />';
                echo '</form>';
                echo '</li>';
              endwhile;
```

**JS**

```
function qty() {
$('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  var fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
  var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
  if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
  } else {
    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
  }
});
$(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  var fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
  var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
  if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
  } else {
    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find the element in the same form

**JS**

```
function qty() {
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var fieldName = $(this).attr('field');

      // find the element in the same form of the button qtyplus:
      var element=$(this).closest('form').find('input[name='+fieldName+']');

      var currentVal = parseInt(element.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        element.val(currentVal + 1);
      } else {
        element.val(0);
    }
  });
  $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fieldName = $(this).attr('field');

    // find the element in the same form of the button qtyminus:
    var element=$(this).closest('form').find('input[name='+fieldName+']');

    var currentVal = parseInt(element.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      element.val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
      element.val(0);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you are targeting all inputs with `name="quantity"` attribute on the page. Try to specify more exactly the input you want changes to be applied. For example:

```
function clickResponse(event) {
    var parent = $(this).closest('form');
    var targetInput = parent.find('input[name="' + $(this).attr('field') + '"]');
    // your code
}
```